# Vue JS re-create the root component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to destroy and re-create the root application component. This is my template:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ num }}
</div>
```

And this is my code:

```
 if (app) {
      app.$destroy();
    } else {
      app = new Vue(Object.assign({
        el: '#app',
      }, { data: { num: Math.random() } }))
    }
```

This code runs on button click, but it doesn't clean the template and refresh the new data I'm passing. Any idea why?

Comment: You may want to use app.$forceUpdate()

Comment: If `app` is set then `app.$destroy()` will be called, but `app = new Vue` not because it is in the `else` block, so it won't be recreated (`app.$destroy` would not magically empty the variable `app`). But way do you want to to it this way, instead of updating the data?

Comment: It's not the full story; I need this functionality.

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? Please specify, if you don't all we can do is guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your attempt so solve a problem in a way that it should not be solve, or that you use vue in the wrong way.

But to you problem, when you execute this code:

```
if (app) {
  app.$destroy();
}
```

Then the documentation state:

> Completely destroy a vm. Clean up its connections with other existing vms, unbind all its directives, turn off all event listeners.

So they don't say that the element to wich the vue app is attached to has to or will change. If you want to clean up the DOM then you need to delete the content manually.

After `app.$destroy()` the `app` variable will still hold the destroyed vue instance (`app` wont be magically unset). So another execution of the code will not trigger the else block.
You also have to set `app` to something that evaluates to falsy.

```
if (app) {
  app.$destroy();
  app = undefined;
}
```

Now `app` is `undefined` so at the next time the `if` statment is evaluated, the `else` block would be evaluated and a new instance is created.

Comment: Can you create a plunker, please? Its still doesn't work. The view doesn't change.

Comment: @undefined you most cerently didn't restore the content of `app` to contain the tempalte markup again. Because this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oth5pf3/2/) works fine. But still, this is mostlikely the wrong way to solve the problem, not matter what you want to achive.

Comment: @undefined that's what you have written in your code. Move the `new Vue` out of the else block and you won't need to clicks. You're not very informative about what exactly you want to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific use case is not specified in the question, but I assume you want to update something that is not being updated automatically.

To update your component you can use

```
this.$forceUpdate()
```

to force a reload of the component.

Comment: I need to re-create the app because I am allowing to pass more than data, you can also pass your methods, computed, etc.